# How to add 1 to an int in a mysql database everytime someone goes to a link in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I have tested everything and nothing works here's my code

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['id']) || !is_numeric($_GET['id'])) { die('Invalid id'); }
$conn = mysqli_connect("redacted", "redacted", "redacted", "redacted");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
"UPDATE affiliate SET clicks WHERE ID='$id' = clicks + 1";
header("Location: https://discord.gg/CjzZRBq");
?>
```

and after I want it to echo on the users dashboard this is what I have

```
<h1>Clicks</h1>
                <br />
                <br />
                You have gotten: <?php $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", 
"id2278622_jonny", "Fencing1", "id2278622_affiliate");
 if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT clicks FROM affiliate WHERE ID='$ID'";
echo "$sql";
?> Clicks!
```

but it just echos the sql code

Comment: try `"UPDATE affiliate SET clicks = clicks + 1 WHERE ID='$id'";`

Comment: @Maraboc i did but it doesnt work either

Comment: Try `"UPDATE affiliate SET clicks = 1001 WHERE ID='$id'";` just to see if you can update the record in the database

Comment: @Maraboc nope didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually sent your query to the database. You've just built a query string. A string that you didn't even save to a variable.

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
"UPDATE affiliate SET clicks WHERE ID='$id' = clicks + 1";
header("Location: https://discord.gg/CjzZRBq");
```

Should be:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$qry= "UPDATE affiliate SET clicks = clicks+1 WHERE ID='$id'";
conn->query($qry);
header("Location: https://discord.gg/CjzZRBq");
```

---

You should also look up [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Casting to an int mitigates risk, but you should definitely be using bind variables.

Comment: @JonathanConnery: hm, looks like I missed an error in the SQL itself. Try again, please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're just echoing `$sql` (which is the query string), rather than passing that SQL command to your database. Also note that your current script is vulnerable to SQL injection. To avoid this, use **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)**:

```
// Retrieve the number of existing clicks
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT clicks FROM affiliate WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($clicks); // Store the result in the $clicks variable

$clicks++; // Increment clicks

// Update the table
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE affiliate SET clicks = ? WHERE ID = ?");
$stmt2->bind_param("si", $clicks, $id); 
$stmt2->execute();

// Close the connection once finished
$conn->close();
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: You have gotten: 
Notice: Undefined variable: sql in /storage/ssd2/622/2278622/public_html/login/Dashboard/index.php on line 60

Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in /storage/ssd2/622/2278622/public_html/login/Dashboard/index.php on line 60

Comment: You shouldn't have gotten that, considering I'm not using the `$sql` variable at all.

Comment: You have gotten: 
Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /storage/ssd2/622/2278622/public_html/login/Dashboard/index.php on line 60

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /storage/ssd2/622/2278622/public_html/login/Dashboard/index.php:60 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Comment: That is now fixed, replacing `$mysqli` with `$conn`.

Comment: why am I updating the clicks in this file?

Comment: I don't understand cause it's a separate file

Comment: You don't have a separate "file"; you have one file and a database. Considering you are only doing a raw counter increment for a database update, you **could** just add `1` to the insert. However, the above method is preferable, as it provides a variable that can be used to **output** the click count, while also using parameterised queries to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: the question was for 2 separate files I wanted to ask them both in one question

Comment: All of that is done in the first file. If you want to echo on the dashboard, you should include the first half of the code (with `$stmt`) on the dashboard as well. Preferably you'd move it to an `include()` or function, as it would be used in two places :)

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /storage/ssd2/622/2278622/public_html/login/Dashboard/index.php on line 62